# Jquery change textfield value and run function

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, onchange

I'm struggeling to get a function to run when a textfield is changed on a button click. So when clicking a plus/min button the text input is changed to a new value. However I want to run a function when textfield value is changed either by those buttons or by typing a value inside the textfield.

Manually typing is working but somehow the function won't run when using a button.

My html (there are multiple table cells like below):

```
<td class="amt">
  <button class="pp_order_min" type="button"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
  <input type="text" maxlength="4" class="pp_count" value="0" name="count[1]" min="0">
  <button class="pp_order_plus" type="button"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
</td>
```

My JS:

```
$(function(){ 

  $('.pp_order_min').bind("click", function(){
   if($(this).next().val() !== '0') $(this).next().val(parseInt($(this).next().val()) - 1);
      $(this).next().trigger('change') // next is the input field
  });
  $('.pp_order_plus').bind("click", function(){
   if($(this).prev().val() !== '999') $(this).prev().val(parseInt($(this).prev().val()) + 1);
      $(this).prev().trigger('change') // prev is the input field
  });

  $('.pp_count').each(function(){ // using each since there are more input fields like this
    $(this).bind('input', function(){ // also tried 'on change' etc
      var amt = $(this).val();
      getNewAttributes(amt);
      console.log(amt);
     });
   });

 });
```

I thought that trigger a change event and the bind an input event would work. But that's not the case! I also tried litterally every on change event that I could think off.

I'm probably overlooking something dumb here! Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you trigger 'input'?

Comment: @HerrSerker: Like I said I was missing something dumb :facepalm

Comment: BTW `.bind()` is deprecated as of jQuery 3. https://api.jquery.com/bind/#entry-longdesc You should use `.on()` instead https://api.jquery.com/on

Comment: @HerrSerker: Yes you're right. I was mixing some old code with new code. Generally not the best idea in terms off making dumb mistakes like above :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should trigger `input` instead of `change`, since this is what you are binding to.

Answer (score 0):

use `.change()` instead trigger

```js
$(function(){ 

  $('.pp_order_min').bind("click", function(){
   if($(this).next().val() !== '0') $(this).next().val(parseInt($(this).next().val()) - 1);
      $(this).next().change() // next is the input field
  });
  $('.pp_order_plus').bind("click", function(){
   if($(this).prev().val() !== '999') $(this).prev().val(parseInt($(this).prev().val()) + 1);
      $(this).prev().change() // prev is the input field
  });

  $('.pp_count').each(function(){ // using each since there are more input fields like this
    $(this).bind('change input', function(){ // also tried 'on change' etc
      var amt = $(this).val();
      //getNewAttributes(amt)
      console.log(amt)
     });
   });

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td class="amt">
  <button class="pp_order_min" type="button"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>-</button>
  <input type="text" maxlength="4" class="pp_count" value="0" name="count[1]" min="0">
  <button class="pp_order_plus" type="button"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>+</button>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to bind only one time change function to input box.

```js
$(function(){ 

  $('.pp_order_min').on("click", function(){
     var currentObj=$(this);
     debugger;
     if(currentObj.next().val()  === '') return;
     if(currentObj.next().val() !== '0') currentObj.next().val(parseInt(currentObj.next().val()) - 1);
     currentObj.next().change(); // next is the input field
  });
  $('.pp_order_plus').on("click", function(){
   var currentObj=$(this);
   debugger;
   if(currentObj.prev().val()  === '') return;
   if(currentObj.prev().val() !== '999') currentObj.prev().val(parseInt(currentObj.prev().val()) + 1);
      currentObj.prev().change(); // prev is the input field
  });
  $('.pp_count').on('change input', function(){ // also tried 'on change' etc
      var amt = $(this).val();
      console.log(amt)
   });
   $('.pp_count').each(function(){ // using each since there are more input fields like this
      $(this).click();// 
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td class="amt">
  <button class="pp_order_min" type="button"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>-</button>
  <input type="text" maxlength="4" class="pp_count" value="0" name="count[1]" min="0">
  <button class="pp_order_plus" type="button"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>+</button>
</td>
```

Please take a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/m6dx3jrv/7/) for multiple textbox.